# Build a library and multiple executables with one target name using cmake

Tags: cmake

I am currently working on migrating from an internal build system to cmake, and I am enjoying it so far.

Our source code is broken up into discrete named components. These components generally will build a library and a set of executables. I have setup cmake with a base CMakeLists.txt and then created a CMakeLists.txt in each code component that is then included in the base. The component CMakeLists.txt have multiple targets in them, one for a library and then a variable number of executables.

With our current system you can type something like:

make component_name

and that will build a library and any executables associated with component_name. Is something like that possible with cmake? Can I use one name to build all of the targets in a CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: If your project is divided over multiple subdirectories, with corresponding CMakeLists.txt, you can also cd into a directory and call make/msbuild/etc there.

Answer (score 5):

First define a custom target, then define the dependencies of the target:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(component_name)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(component_name lib1 lib2 exe1 exe2)
```